# Difference between $f \circ f = f$ and $f \circ f = id$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do we interpret either? Is $f\circ f = f \iff f(f(x)) = f(x)$? Is $f \circ f = id \iff f(f(x)) = f(x)?$

Comment: Presumably you now realize that while $f = id$ (the identity function) is one way that $f \circ f$ could equal $f$, this is not the only way it can happen.  For example, constant functions will have the former property, but not in general the latter.

Comment: The first statement is a definition.  f circ f = f means f(f (x)) = f (x) for all x.  The second is something you have to prove.  f (f (x)) =x for all x iff f (f (x)) = f (x) for all x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $id(x)=x$.

$f\circ f=f \to f(f(x))=f(x)$ and $f\circ f=id \to f(f(x))=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a set and $f:X\to X$ be a function. Then, by definition, the function $f\circ f:X\to X$ is the one such that
$$
\forall x\in X:f\circ f(x)=f(f(x)).
$$
Also, we have the function $id_X:X\to X$ defined by
$$
\forall x\in X:id_X(x)=x.
$$
Hence,
$$
f\circ f=f\iff\forall x\in X:f(f(x))=f(x)
$$
and
$$
f\circ f=id_X\iff\forall x\in X:f(f(x))=x.
$$
As you can see, those two expressions say different things.

Answer (score 0):

The first one says $f(f(x))=f(x)$, the second says that $f(f(x))=x$.

Note that $f(x)=1$ satisfies the first one, but not the second one, and $g(x)=1/x$ satisfies only the second one (for nonzero $x$).